# extract hessian from optim() function in r

Tags: r

i wrote the following code to optimise a posterior of the binary model, i want to extract the hessian matrix in order to find the observed information matrix

observed information matrix = - hessian

the r-code is following,

```
 posterior.mode <- function(y, x)
{
# sample size
n <- length(y)
# number of betas
d <- ncol(x)
# the log posterior as a function of the vector beta for subject i data
log.like_one <- function(i, beta)
{
  # p_{i}, given X_{i} and beta
  Phi.xb <- pnorm( sum(x[i,] * beta) )
  return( log(1 - Phi.xb) + y[i]*log( Phi.xb/(1 - Phi.xb) ) )
}
# log likelihood of the entire sample
loglike <- function(beta)
{
  L <- 0
  for(ii in 1:n) L <- L + log.like_one(ii,beta)
  return(L)
}
# *negative* log posterior of the entire sample
log.posterior <- function(beta) -loglike(beta) + ((beta/2)-log(1+exp(beta)))
# return the beta which optimizes the log posterior.
# initial values are arbitrarily chosen to be all 0’s.
return( optim( rep(0,d), log.posterior), hessian=TRUE)$hessian

}
```

from :
return( optim( rep(0,d), log.posterior), hessian=TRUE)$hessian

how can i extract the hessian and assign it to observed information matrix??

any help?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is. You get the hessian matrix with `hessian = TRUE`, right? (Edit: and with `$hessian` you grab it.) Can't you just multiply it by `-1`?

Comment: how can i store it

Comment: i want to store the -hessian in   info.mat<-( -hessian)  so that i can print it

Comment: If you wrote this code, you already know how to return a value from a function. The only problem that I see is that you miswrote the last line, it should be `return( optim( rep(0,d), log.posterior, hessian=TRUE)$hessian)`. But from there, you can just run something like `info.mat <- -posterior.mode(y, x)`, right?

Comment: no, we should extract it from optim

Answer (score 0):

As @slamballais indicated, you have typos in your return statement.

You haven't given us a MWE, so I'm using (part of) an example from *the online help* for `optim`.  (The online help is always worth a read.  It's amazing what you can find there...)

```
myFunction <- function() {
  -optim(c(-1.2,1), fr, NULL, method = "BFGS", hessian = TRUE)$hessian
}

answer <- myFunction()
answer
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] -801.6881  399.9218
[2,]  399.9218 -200.0000
```